# Butterknife onItemClick вместе с View

Tags: android, recyclerview, butterknife, android-annotations

Вопрос таков. Как использовать @OnItemClick(RecyclerView) в Butterknife вместе с View? Есть ли такая возможность? Если можно пример т.к. на просторах интернета мало что извесно.Заранее спасибо)

Comment: А зачем вам `View`, если данные в них берутся из модели? Изменять `View`? Изменения надо сохранять в отдельные списки/массивы, так как списки не сохраняют изменения при прокрутке

Comment: Впринципе так оно и есть, но я не знаю как правильно описать метод с @OnItemClick(R.id.RecyclerView) чтобы хотябы position был

Comment: попробуйте просто добавить параметр `int position` в ваш метод

Comment: и кстати, если вы используете `RecyclerView`, то вам нужно ставить слушатель аннотацией `@OnClick` на `View`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771701/how-to-use-butterknife-onitemclick-with-recyclerview